# Can't get NSTableView to display any text whatsoever

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I've been developing on iOS for some time, but am very new to Cocoa development, and something seemingly very simple is stumping me.

I have an NSTableView, hooked up to a subclass of NSWindowController as both datasource and delegate. I have an array of "File" objects (my model class) and want to populate one column of my tableview with file types, and another with timestamps.

The dataSource methods  are definitely being called, as verified by setting breakpoints. In fact, I end up with an appropriate number of rows that are selectable...but none of them display anything. I even tried returning an arbitrary string literal in `objectValueForTableColumn`, for all rows and columns, and still nothing.

I think I'm probably stuck on how tableViews work in iOS, but obviously they are very different here...I am used to configuring and returning a cell myself, but here we just pass AnyObject??? How exactly does the tableView know how to display AnyObject? I'm really struggling with the conceptual understanding here. Appreciate any help.

Comment: How many times `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row` method is  getting called? Code snippet of this method will help.

Comment: It is getting called for each item in my data array. I didn't think it made sense to include a snippet because right now, in an attempt to get something to work, I'm just returning an arbitrary string each time...method body is one line: return "Test"

Comment: Are you using cell or view based cell views?