# Cannot get NSTableView to populate

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

In a Swift OSX Cocoa program, I cannot for the life of me get any text to display from a simple two-dimensional array into a two-column NSTableView. The Table View is inside a window in the xib. The dataSource outlet and delegate outlet, and tableView referencing outlet, are all connected to File's Owner. In the controller's .swift code file, I have declared

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
```

and that is connected to the xib, so my problem doesn't seem to be the same as [this one]. I want to populate tableView with an array, but like [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902094/cant-get-nstableview-to-display-any-text-whatsoever) I simplified it to populating with a string literal just to try and get any text at all. (The previous poster never seems to have gotten an answer, but he didn't post a code snippet so I will do that.) numberOfRowsInTableView returns 2, as it's currently supposed to. And here's tableView, excluding currently commented-out code:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject!
{
    var newString = ""
    newString = "Help!"
    return newString    
}
```

As far as I can tell, I *should* get a 2x2 table with each cell containing the word "Help!" But I don't. The table remains empty. Why?

EDIT in response to comment below: The commenter recommends I drag to Application under Objects, which I think is referring to something like this?

[image: Objects in document outline]

For whatever reason, I don't have that. My document outline for the .xib looks like this:

[image]

Maybe that's a clue as to what's wrong?

Comment: Don't connect it the File Owner, connect `dataSource`, `delegate` to the App Delegate in the left pane

Comment: Do you mean Application? (under Placeholders with File's Owner) I tried connecting dataSource and delegate to those and the problem was the same as before. I also tried connecting them to AppDelegate.swift itself but as far as I can tell that is impossible - I drag the line from dataSource or delegate over AppDelegate.swift or any of the other file names, and it just doesn't make a connection.

Comment: Under Objects, there's a Delegate, That's what I meant by App Delegate

Comment: Are you using Cocoa bindings with or without an array controller or `viewForTableColumn`?

Comment: I've been trying to do it programmatically without bindings, and without an array controller (the user wouldn't be modifying the table directly). 

Regarding the Delegate under Objects... I need to show you my screen grabs and I don't think I can do that down here, so I'm going to modify the question above.

Comment: If I need to use bindings or an array controller I will, but I was trying to make it simpler; it didn't seem like they should be necessary.

Comment: Then you need to implement `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`

Comment: @vadian OK, thanks. So I am trying to do that. As far as I can tell, that requires that I return a cell object instead of text. 

So I have replaced return newString with this code:

`let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("Attribute Table", owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView`
        
`cell.textField?.stringValue = newString`
        
`return cell`

But it tells me NSTableCellView doesn't have a textField member, so I can't do that.

Comment: [This documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableCellView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTableCellView/textField) seems to indicate I should be able to get a textField member using Interface Builder, but I can't figure out how.